# Is this a separable first order ODE? It seems that the method of integrating factor/Leibniz's method does not apply.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem**

Consider the first order ODE:
$$3 x \frac{d y}{d x}+9 y=2 x y^{\frac{5}{3}}$$
Is this ODE separable? If not, how should its solution be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{3}{x}y=(2/3)y^{5/3} \implies y^{-5/3}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{3}{x} y^{-2/3}=\frac{2}{3}$$
This is Bernoulli equation, take $y^{-2/3}=v \implies \frac{-2}{3}y^{-5/3} dy =dv$
$$\implies \frac{dv}{dx}+\frac{-2}{x}v=-4/9$$
This is linear ODE for which IF is $e^{-2\ln x}=1/x^2$
It solution can be written as
$$v=x^2 \int (-4/9)(1/x^2) dx+Cx^2 \implies v=\frac{4x}{9}+Cx^2 \implies y^{-2/3}=\frac{4x}{9}+Cx^2$$ $$ \implies y=(Cx^2-\frac{4x}{9})^{-3/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$3 x \frac{d y}{d x}+9 y=2 x y^{\frac{5}{3}}$$
$$ x dy+3 ydx=\frac 23 x y^{\frac{5}{3}}dx$$
Divide by $xy$:
$$  d(\ln y)+d(\ln x^3)=\frac 23  y^{\frac{2}{3}}dx$$
$$  d(\ln (yx^3)=\frac 23  y^{\frac{2}{3}}dx$$
$$  \dfrac {d(\ln (yx^3)}{x^2y^{2/3}}=\frac 2{3  x^{2}}dx$$
Substitute $u=x^3y$
$$  \dfrac {du}{u^{5/3}}=\frac 2{3  x^{2}}dx$$
Integrate.
$$ -\frac 32 {(x^³y)^{-2/3}}=-\frac 2 {3x}  +C$$
Finally:
$$  y^{-2/3}(x)=\frac 4{9}  x+Kx^2$$